# telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Tags: 16.04, docker, telnet

I am **inside docker** and I have installed **zookeeper** and trying to test it using **telnet**
But it is not working

```
$ telnet localhost 2181
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I tried these also

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 2181
telnet 172.17.0.2 2181
```

But same error.

**netstat** status

```
# netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
```

Please help.

Comment: Sir, it's been six years almost since, but maybe there any solution you've found?

Answer (score 1):

Verify zookeeper is actually running, via

```
ps aux | grep -i zookeeper
```

If it is, then it may not be bound to 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0. So check which IP address it's actually bound to,

```
netstat -tlpn
```

Then try to telnet to it using that address.

Comment: Just now I found even `telnet locahost ` is not working. Has same error.

Comment: Simply using `telnet localhost` would attempt to connect to a local server process listening port 23. Most servers/containers I know don't enable telnet servers by default since it's insecure.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it.

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `netstat -tlpn`

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: It's clear from your netstat output that there's no server process listening. Are you sure zookeeper is running? I suggest trying out this guide if you haven't already: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html

Comment: Did you check your firewall?

Answer (score 1):

check your ubuntu system log with this command

**sudo gedit /var/log/syslog**

and if you will see this error "execv( /usr/sbin/tcpd ) failed: No such file or directory" then run this command

**sudo apt-get install tcpd**

it will solve your problem (if not then you need to search your system error on google)